# VBA basic algorithm doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I have a risk heat map in excel. I have  a formula that should take the probability and impact of each reference and place it in an appropriate cell in the table. It looks like this:

```
Function ProbSevScore(Prob As Integer, Sev As Integer, Nbr As Range)
Application.Volatile True
Dim cell As Range

ProbSevScore = ""

For Each cell In Nbr
PScore = Right(cell.Offset(0, 1), 1) + 0
SScore = Right(cell.Offset(0, 2), 1) + 0
If PScore = Prob Then
If SScore = Sev Then
If Len(ProbSevScore) > 0 Then
ProbSevScore = ProbSevScore & ","
End If
ProbSevScore = ProbSevScore & cell.Value
End If
End If
Next cell

End Function
```

It is a copy of the algorithm outlined in this tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XqCX4pKFPM

I have some slight differences in my map, the probability and severity are called different things and the axis are reversed but these things are not important.

When I try to use this formula, nothing appears in the cell that I run the function in. It is left blank, no #VALUE error or anything.

What am I doing wrong? Have I copied the code incorrectly? The algorithm works in the video! Does this code work for you guys?

Me calling function: [image]

Document: https://www.sendspace.com/file/liw29j

Comment: This UDF works OK, so there is probably a problem with parameters on your side.

Comment: You mean selecting the right parameters? I've done it several times, I'm 100% sure I'm selecting the right parameters!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot with your sample data and showing how you call ProbSevScore?

Comment: Happily, give me some time though I need to load up a work laptop and finish doing something first

Comment: Added a screenshot. Will need to zoom in to see formula. But add Prob first, sev second, then select the range.

Comment: ProbSevScore gives correct result (280,283) with the same UDF and the same data layout on my side. I'm not sure what else could be wrong, can you upload your file?

Comment: How do I upload files?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate on the UDF thing. What I did was I loaded up an Excel doc and pressed Alt + F11 and inserted a new module. Then function could then be called from the document. This didn't work, should I do something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72991/discussion-between-user3964075-and-turgidwizard).

Comment: As user3964075 has reported, the function itself seems to work OK.  First off, have you tried placing your function code in a module in the same workbook as your heat map and data; and recalculating?

Comment: Pretty sure, the module is in the same overall document as the spreadsheet, in a sub-folder. I uploaded the document to sendspace and linked it in a recent edit. Have a look. It must be my setup if the code works for you. I'm not sure about VBA, my only experience with it is the tutorial video. Maybe my version of excel is not correct, maybe I don't have the libraries for the code that I'm using (though I suspect there should be an error) or maybe I don't have things saved correctly. Should I save the module somewhere special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UDF doesn't work for you, because `Likelihood` and `Impact` columns in input table are not integers. With `General` format applied, the table looks like that:

[image]

This part of VBA code:

```
PScore = Right(cell.Offset(0, 1), 1) + 0
SScore = Right(cell.Offset(0, 2), 1) + 0
```

cuts the last character of cell value (not displayed formatted text) and converts it to integer, so with your sample data, the first pair is `9,1` (not `3,2`)

To solve it, you should convert input data to integers in UDF:

```
PScore = Right(Round(cell.Offset(0, 1)), 1) + 0
SScore = Right(Round(cell.Offset(0, 2)), 1) + 0
```

If your data contains only numbers (and no text like in the tutorial video), you don't need the `Right` function and casting:

```
PScore = Round(cell.Offset(0, 1))
SScore = Round(cell.Offset(0, 2))
```

Comment: Can't get it to work, I changed the two lines of code to 'PScore = Round(cell.Offset(0, 1), 1) + 0
SScore = Round(cell.Offset(0, 2), 1) + 0'

What am I doing wrong, did I misunderstand? the + 0 converts it to an integer and the Round() makes sure that the right data is included?

Comment: @TurgidWizard `+0` converts text to number, and `Round` rounds the given number to nearest integer. Just copy the two lines of code from my answer and replace the lines of code in your UDF. The code in your comment is a combination of my 2 versions and it won't work

Comment: Really awesome, thanks a lot, you've been really helpful all the way through - big ups!